# Função calcula até certo ponto e para

Tags: c, funções, double

Estou com uma variável `double` fazendo uma conta mas ela chega até um limite [no meu caso 1.367879] e não aumenta mais.

O código está rodando normalmente, o problema é o resultado que não passa de 1.367879

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double calcSoma(int n);
long int fatorial(int n);

int main () {
    int termos;
do {
    printf("Digite a qtd de termos (>= 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &termos);
}while(termos < 5);
 printf("\nO somatorio para %d termos eh %f", termos, calcSoma(termos));

}

double calcSoma (int n){
    double s = 1;
    int i, numerador = 0, valFat = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        numerador = numerador + 2;
        valFat = valFat + 2; //numeros impares
        s = s + (double)numerador/fatorial(valFat);
    }
return s;
}

long int fatorial(int n){
    long int fat = 0;
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        fat = n * (fatorial(n-1));
    }
    return fat;
}
```

Comment: Na função `calcSoma()` o valor que vais adicionando a `s` torna-se cada vez mais pequeno **muito** rápido. `numerador / fatorial(valFat)` é um número cada vez mais perto de zero. `1.367879 + 0.0000000000000....0006576423` nunca sai de 1.367879

Comment: Pode ser isso. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Na função `calcSoma()` o valor que vais adicionando a `s` torna-se cada vez mais pequeno **muito** rápido.

`numerador / fatorial(valFat)` é um número cada vez mais perto de zero.

`1.367879 + 0.0000000000000....0006576423` nunca sai de 1.367879

Valor somado a `s` com

```
i = 0; // numerador/fatorial(valFat) ==  2/ 3!  == 0.333...
i = 1; // numerador/fatorial(valFat) ==  4/ 5!  == 0.0333...
i = 2; //                                6/ 7!  == 0.00119...
i = 3; //                                8/ 9!  == 0.0000220...
i = 4; //                               10/ 11! == 0.000000250...
i = 5; //                               12/ 13! == 0.00000000192...
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe um limite do número que pode ser representado pelos tipos numéricos, esta fórmula está trabalhando com números grandes demais. Precisa criar ou usar algo pronto que saiba lidar com valores tão grandes. O que não é algo fácil de fazer. Minha sugestão é usar o [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Mudando a [formatação para apresentar o número em notação científica](https://ideone.com/Vap6BP) ajuda ver melhor o número (neste caso não muito).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double calcSoma(int n);
long int fatorial(int n);

int main () {
    int termos;
do {
    printf("Digite a qtd de termos (>= 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &termos);
}while(termos < 5);
 printf("\nO somatorio para %d termos eh %e", termos, calcSoma(termos));

}

double calcSoma (int n){
    double s = 1;
    int i, numerador = 0, valFat = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        numerador = numerador + 2;
        valFat = valFat + 2; //numeros impares
        s = s + (double)numerador/fatorial(valFat);
    }
return s;
}

long int fatorial(int n){
    long int fat = 0;
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        fat = n * (fatorial(n-1));
    }
    return fat;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Sum.c).